# 18.04 server: AWS slow network upload

Tags: networking, server, amazon-ec2

I have an AWS EC2 instance of Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

When I created the instance, the network was 1 gbps up and down. After using it for awhile, the upload is stuck at 4.2 mbps, but with 1 gbps download. This has happened to me before on different instances of Ubuntu. Of course I have rebooted it which did not resolve the issue.

I changed instance type and I can get 2.9 gbps download but still stuck at 4.2 mbps upload. It seems that the OS is somehow messed up.

I haven't done that much to the system. I installed GDAL, Imagemagick, AWS CLI and processed some images, uploaded to AWS S3 (tried to anyway, but at 4.2mbps I can't).

What steps can I take to find the issue?

I should note that AWS says there is nothing wrong on their end, and I can use Centos 7 in the same availability zone without issue.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I know this response is late, but I'm posting it here in case anyone comes across this issue in the future and finds this post as I have.

The issue is actually with the packaged version of the speedtest-cli on Ubuntu 18.04. I don't know exactly what the issue is that causes the upload to be capped around 4mbps but I have found plenty of other people that have had this exact issue.

The solution is to remove the packaged version and use the latest version from github instead.

```
apt remove speedtest-cli
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/master/speedtest.py
```